# Order by sublist in mongodb with c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have there objects:

```
public class Template{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public List<TemplateRow> TemplateRows{get;set;}
}

public class TemplateRow{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public int Index{Get;set;}
}
```

1. I want to fetch TemplateRows and **sort by Index**. (where template id is some id)
2. I want to fetch few Template and make sure its TemplateRows are **sorted by Index**

Can I be done with c#?

**Update** this will not sort:

```
collection.Find(Query<Template>.EQ(x => x.Id , templateId))
    .OrderBy(x => x.TemplateRows.OrderBy(b => b.Index))
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes it can. What did you try?

Comment: @gustavodidomenico I added the query

Comment: Ok :). So, you in fact not sorting the sub documents, but the root documents. Unfortunately the only way to perform your operation is with an aggregation of the results (after the find) and then sorting it.

Comment: Not sure about your wording. Could you post a simple *example* of what you want sorted, exactly?

Comment: @mnemosyn I want that the sub list `TemplateRows` will be sorted by `Index`

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't currently support an operator to sort the array fields on the way out. However, it does provide a way for you to sort the fields on the way in. In many ways, this is much better because sorting only happens once at update time. (You'll of course, need to make sure they are sorted at insertion time).

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort